# V-Star 250 No Power After Jumping

Tags: electrical, battery, motorcycle

I have a 2012 V-star 250. Everything was running fine until I left the lights on all day while I was at work (RIP). Battery was dead so I jumped it with my car. Started up fine and rode it about 20 minutes home. Next time I tried to start it the battery was still dead so I jumped it again and let it run for 40 minutes before it spontaneously died. Next time I tried to jump it wouldn't turn over but the lights still came on. I assumed at this point that the battery was too far gone so I bought a new one (they charged it before I brought it home). Installed the new battery and nothing. Lights won't come on, don't get a single sound when I hit the starter. I've checked the fuses and they're all fine. Made sure the kill switch was off and the bike was in neutral, kickstand was up. Even tried jumping again and still didn't even get the dash lights to come on. Not sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Two things: 1) Did you check the voltage of the new battery to make sure it was sitting over 12vdc? 2) Are you sure you don't have the battery hooked in backwards?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, it was over 12 and I just double checked and it is hooked up the correct way.

Comment: You might want to check the connections to ensure there's no corrosion on them (cable side), which would prevent a good connection.

Comment: Are you sure you put all of the connectors back on the battery?

Comment: Update: I'm an idiot. haha somehow when I was putting the new battery in I disconnected the wire running to the fuses. I was 5 seconds away from giving up and calling a shop when I found the problem. Runs like a charm now. Thanks for everyone's input!